# WebViewProcessControl initialization crash

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, webview, windows-runtime

## The Problem

I'm trying to use the "modern" web view API in my Win32 program, but when I initialize `WebViewControlProcess`, the program hangs for a couple of seconds, and then suddenly exits.

## Minimal Example

```
// cl minimal.cpp /EHsc /std:c++17 /await windowsapp.lib

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Web.UI.Interop.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Web::UI::Interop;

int main(void) {
    winrt::init_apartment();
    printf("Hello\n");

    WebViewControlProcess webviews = WebViewControlProcess();

    printf("    world!\n");
}
```

#### Expected Output

```
Hello
    world!
```

#### Actual Output

```
Hello
```

## Environment

I'm using Windows 10.0.17134 (1803).

Comment: https://github.com/fobrs/WebViewSample.Win32.cppwinrt might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out WebViewProcessControl needs you to `winrt::init_apartment(apartment_type::single_threaded);`. I don't know why it needs a single-threaded apartment, but it works.