# Why is WebViewControlProcess.CreateWebViewControlAsync() never completing?

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-runtime, interop

I’m trying to write some Rust code that uses [`Windows.Web.UI.Interop.WebViewControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop) (which is a Universal Windows Platform out-of-process wrapper expressly designed so Win32 apps can use EdgeHTML), and it’s all compiling, but not working properly at runtime.

The relevant code boils down to this, using the winit, winapi and winrt crates:

```
use winit::os::windows::WindowExt;
use winit::{EventsLoop, WindowBuilder};

use winapi::winrt::roapi::{RoInitialize, RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED};
use winapi::shared::winerror::S_OK;

use winrt::{RtDefaultConstructible, RtAsyncOperation};
use winrt::windows::foundation::Rect;
use winrt::windows::web::ui::interop::WebViewControlProcess;

fn main() {
    assert!(unsafe { RoInitialize(RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED) } == S_OK);

    let mut events_loop = EventsLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .build(&events_loop)
        .unwrap();

    WebViewControlProcess::new()
        .create_web_view_control_async(
            window.get_hwnd() as usize as i64,
            Rect {
                X: 0.0,
                Y: 0.0,
                Width: 800.0,
                Height: 600.0,
            },
        )
        .expect("Creation call failed")
        .blocking_get()
        .expect("Creation async task failed")
        .expect("Creation produced None");
}
```

The `WebViewControlProcess` instantiation works, and the `CreateWebViewControlAsync` function does seem to care about the value it received as `host_window_handle` (pass it 0, or one off from the actual `HWND` value, and it complains). Yet the `IAsyncOperation` stays determinedly at `AsyncStatus.Started` (0), and so the `blocking_get()` call hangs indefinitely.

[A full, runnable demonstration of the issue (with a bit more instrumentation)](https://github.com/chris-morgan/webviewcontrol-rs/tree/a1c65420564971e66a42cc3609f5656713883644).

I get the feeling that the `WebViewControlProcess` is at fault: its `ProcessId` is stuck at 0, and it doesn’t look to have spawned any subprocess. The `ProcessExited` event does not *seem* to be being fired (I attached something to it immediately after instantiation, is there opportunity for it to be fired before that?). Calling `Terminate()` fails as one might expect in such a situation, `E_FAIL`.

Have I missed some sort of initialization for using `Windows.Web.UI.Interop`? Or is there some other reason why it’s not working?

Comment: It's been a long time since we've seen you, friend! Good to have you back (even if only for a little while!)

Comment: @Shepmaster: after not having used Rust for anything particularly serious for a couple of years, I am finally seriously working on a project (of my own, still) which is solid Rust, and it’s a delight to get back to using Rust seriously. Good to see you again, too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was threading-related: the winit crate was doing its event loop in a different thread, and I did not realise this; I had erroneously assumed winit to be a harmless abstraction, which it turned out not *quite* to be.

I discovered this when I tried minimising and porting a known-functioning C++ example, this time doing all the Win32 API calls manually rather than using winit, so that the translation was correct. I got it to work, and discovered this:

The `IAsyncOperation` is fulfilled in the event loop, deep inside a `DispatchMessageW` call. *That* is when the `Completion` handler is called. Thus, for the operation to complete, you must run an event loop on the same thread. (An event loop on another thread doesn’t do anything.) Otherwise, it stays in the `Started` state.

Fortunately, winit [is already moving to a new event loop which operates in the same thread](https://github.com/tomaka/winit/issues/459#issuecomment-461041982), with the Windows implementation having landed a few days ago; when I migrated my code to use the eventloop-2.0 branch of winit, and to using the `Completed` handler instead of `blocking_get()`, it all started working.

I shall clarify about the winrt crate’s `blocking_get()` call which would normally be the obvious solution while prototyping: you can’t use it in this case because it causes deadlock, since it blocks until the `IAsyncOperation` completes, but the `IAsyncOperation` will not complete until you process messages in the event loop (`DispatchMessageW`), which will never happen because you’re blocking the thread.

Comment: winrt-rs now supports async-await https://github.com/microsoft/winrt-rs/pull/251

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `WebViewProcessControl` with `winrt::init_apartment();` And it may needs a single-threaded apartment(according to the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754235/webviewprocesscontrol-initialization-crash)).

More attention on [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> Lastly, power users might notice the apppearance of the Desktop App
>   Web Viewer (previously named Win32WebViewHost), an internal system app
>   representing the Win32 WebView, in the following places:
>
> ● In the Windows 10 Action Center. The source of these notifications
>   should be understood as from a WebView hosted from a Win32 app.
>
> ● In the device access settings UI
>   (Settings->Privacy->Camera/Location/Microphone). Disabling any of
>   these settings denies access from all WebViews hosted in Win32 apps.

Comment: Alas, I’ve already got this, and it does take effect: `RoInitialize(RO_INIT_SINGLETHREADED)` is the equivalent of `winrt::init_apartment` in single-threaded mode for Rust code. (Look at the definition of `init_apartment` in winrt/base.h—it’s a `WINRT_RoInitialize` call plus turning an error `hresult` into a thrown exception.) Without the `RoInitialize` call, or with it multi-threaded instead of single-threaded, the code fails as soon as you try to initialise the `WebViewControlProcess`. But with it, it gets past that line and just seems like it might be failing to actually spawn the process?

Comment: So, does it show "Creation call failed"? Since you said  *its `ProcessId` is stuck at 0, and it doesn’t look to have spawned any subprocess.*

Comment: No, it gets past that: “the `IAsyncOperation` stays determinedly at `AsyncStatus.Started` (0), and so the `blocking_get()` call hangs indefinitely.” I don’t know for certain what the expected behaviour of the `WebViewControlProcess` is (since it’s not working), but I *guess* that it’s supposed to spawn a subprocess (I see no such thing happening), and that `ProcessId` should then be a non-zero integer.